# Internet Explorer stores working data under %TEMP% instead of normal locations

Tags: internet-explorer

Internet Explorer normally stores its working data in various special locations. For example:

```
Cookies  ->  %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
History  ->  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\History
Cache    ->  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
```

However, for some reason, Internet Explorer occasionally stops using the normal locations and instead creates new folders under `%TEMP%` and/or `%TEMP%\Low` for this data. For example:

```
Cookies  ->  %TEMP%\Cookies
             %TEMP%\Low\Cookies
History  ->  %TEMP%\History
             %TEMP%\Low\History
Cache    ->  %TEMP%\Temporary Internet Files
             %TEMP%\Low\Temporary Internet Files
```

When this happens, the configured locations have *not* changed. The registry entries still point to `%APPDATA%` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%`. Internet Explorer is ignoring these settings and putting its working files in `%TEMP%` despite being configured otherwise.

Why does Internet Explorer do this, and how can make it use the normal locations again?

Comment: is this a personal machine, or part of a domain? This may be a situation in which a  GPO is overriding the defaults - if it's part of a domain

Comment: It's my personal machine; no non-default group policy settings, not part of a domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your Browsing History via .. Tools > Internet Options > General > Browsing History > Settings  . you'll see "Move Folder" , "View Objects" , "View Files". if not, you can reset settings via Advance Tab.

Comment: That's not the problem. This setting still shows `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files`, but Internet Explorer is ignoring it and putting its files under `%TEMP%`.